# How to draw separater in giftedchat?

Tags: javascript, chat

I would like to draw separator such like "---- alredy read ----" with
giftedchat (https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat).

I think it is basic function for chat program, and can do with giftedchat.
I googled a lot, but can't find the way.

Would you teach me how to?  I wolud like to draw like below.

```
 |----------|
 | Hello    |
 |----------|

--------- alredy read --------

                 |----------|
                 | Hi       |
                 |----------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may use `System Message` to achieve this. The example is already shows in the [React-Native-Gifted-Chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat).

> e.g. System Message

```
{
  _id: 1,
  text: 'This is a system message',
  createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
  system: true,
  // Any additional custom parameters are passed through
}
```

Then you may use the props `renderSystemMessage` to style your message.

```
const renderSystemMessage = (props) => {
  return <Text>-----{props.currentMessage.text}-----</Text>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you Lewis!  I missed system message.  Thanks again.